# Windows Server 2022 Standard - Pack 5 cal's

Tags: windows

I have a Windows Server 2022 Standard installed and activated, and I have a pack of 5 Cal's to activate, as a user cal. And here lies the doubt: How and where do I activate this pack?

Comment: My thanks to Lukas Pietscher (Wiresoft), for the quick clarification. Basically he answers the question by saying that there is no activation or installation, it is a mere contractual role.